# Center the launch and login screen logo image

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, launch-screen

I am trying to center the same logo for the launch screen and login screen, one a bitmap and one an ImageView respectively, the images are slightly off from one another

Here is the bitmap XML snippet:

```
<bitmap
      android:src="@drawable/logo"
      android:gravity="center"/>
```

Here is the ImageView XML snippet:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/logo_image"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:scaleType="centerInside"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
```

I have tried to change the ImageView's scaleType variable (tried "fitXY" and "fitCenter") but no luck.

To reiterate, my goal is to have the ImageView's logo be at the exact same spot as the bitmap's logo, when the launch screen disappears.

Comment: What is parent layout for both? paste complete XML for both screens

Comment: For imageView: RelativeLayout->ScrollView->LinerLayout->RelativeLayout->ImageView.   For bitmap: layer-list->item->bitmap